# How to put into 'title' attribute all the content of the certain tag?

Tags: html, title

```
<p title="...">Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.</p>
```

How to put all the paragraph content into `title` attribute? Just to copy them or there are some other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set the `title` to the value of `innerHTML`

```js
const el = document.querySelector('p');
el.setAttribute('title', el.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p title="...">Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.</p>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by `setAttribute` function

```js
let ptag = document.getElementById("myptag");

ptag.setAttribute("title",ptag.innerText);
```

```html
<p id="myptag" title="...">Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.Inner information.</p>
```

Comment: @AntonHPL Has your problem been solved? simply use `setAttribute`